# Mostrar fecha actual en input tipo date con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, entrada

Necesito mostrar la fecha actual en un `input` tipo `date` en vez de que salga `dd/mm/aaaa`.

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Agrega mas información a tu pregunta como  una descripción  mas especifica de lo que intentaste y lo que deseas que pase.

Answer (score 11):

Podrias intentar algo como lo siguiente:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var fecha = new Date(); //Fecha actual
  var mes = fecha.getMonth()+1; //obteniendo mes
  var dia = fecha.getDate(); //obteniendo dia
  var ano = fecha.getFullYear(); //obteniendo año
  if(dia<10)
    dia='0'+dia; //agrega cero si el menor de 10
  if(mes<10)
    mes='0'+mes //agrega cero si el menor de 10
  document.getElementById('fechaActual').value=ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="fechaActual" value="" >
```

Comment: esta respuesta tiene problemas de escalabilidad a pesar de que usas un id para poblar el input, lo tienes amarrado la logica... yo preferiria pasarlo por un argumento...

Answer (score 6):

Para hacerlo deberías usar JavaScript.

Podes utilizar el objeto `Date`, te recomiendo que leas un poco acerca de el para darle un uso más específico

```js
n =  new Date();
//Año
y = n.getFullYear();
//Mes
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
//Día
d = n.getDate();

//Lo ordenas a gusto.
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d + "/" + m + "/" + y;
```

```html
<h1 id="date"></h1>
```

Comment: El OP pide cargar el valor en in `input[type=date]` no en un div.  El formato presentado en esta respuesta no será compatible

Answer (score 2):

Este es un ejemplo super sencillo con el objeto ***Date*** espero pueda servirte

```js
 var fecha = new Date();
document.getElementById("FechaActual").value = fecha.toJSON().slice(0,10);
```

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="FechaActual">
```

Comment: no es escalable

Answer (score 2):

Por que no utilizas la libreria [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) es mas sencillo manipular las fecha e incluso si también pretendes manejarla en localizaciones.

```
moment.locale();         // en
moment().format('LT');   // 2:44 PM
moment().format('LTS');  // 2:44:36 PM
moment().format('L');    // 02/03/2022
moment().format('l');    // 2/3/2022
moment().format('LL');   // February 3, 2022
moment().format('ll');   // Feb 3, 2022
moment().format('LLL');  // February 3, 2022 2:44 PM
moment().format('lll');  // Feb 3, 2022 2:44 PM
moment().format('LLLL'); // Thursday, February 3, 2022 2:44 PM
moment().format('llll'); // Thu, Feb 3, 2022 2:44 PM
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta, ninguno de los formatos presentados es valido para el value un `input[type=date]`. Promueve el uso de una librería que desde el 2020 sus mismos autores desaconsejan.

Answer (score 1):

El elemento `input` cuando es del tipo `date` tiene una propiedad llamada `valueAsDate`, con el cual pues asignar o retornar el valor del `input` pero usando un objeto del tipo `Date`

```js
MyInput.valueAsDate = new Date();
```

```html
<input id="MyInput" type="date" />
```

Comment: no es escalable tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

```
    const fecha = new Date(respuesta["fecha_nac"]);
    const [day, month, year] = respuesta["fecha_nac"].split("/");
    console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
    document.getElementById("editarFechaNac").value =
    year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: La constate `fecha` sobra en este código. Además esto solo funciona si `respuesta["fecha_nac"]` está en formato `dd/MM/yyyy` y por supuesto tampoco usa la fecha actual que es lo que el OP quería

Answer (score -1):

```js
var fechaActual = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementById('fechaActual').value= fechaActual
```

```html
<input id ="fechaActual" type="date">
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar la biblioteca *date-fns* para conseguir mas fácil eso.

Código JavaScript:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';

let fechaActual = new Date();
let fechaFormateada = format(fechaActual, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Input html:

```
<input type="date" :value="fechaFormateada">
```

Comment: Como va a ser más fácil bajar una librería solo para rellenar un input?!

Comment: Si trabajas en un proyecto en el cual tienes que utilizar mas veces es tipo de formateo de fechas es mucho mas fácil utilizar esta librería que formatear tu a mano la fecha no crees? @Yussef

Comment: No lo creo, crear un función para formatear la fecha (por ejemplo como la que está en la respuesta más votada de esta pregunta) y aplicar dicha función es mucho más simple que tener que descargar una librería y tener que leer la documentación para saber usarla. Te recomiendo una publicación https://www.davidhaney.io/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/

Answer (score -1):

Hay muchas formas de responder a tu pregunta... y cuesta hacerlo por que muchos creeran que no has intentado nada.

Pero seguire la premisa de que el bien es para la comunidad en general.

A dia de hoy la manera en que yo lo haria serian las siguientes:

```js
// Obtener la fecha actual en formato YYYY-MM-DD
const today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

// Asignar la fecha actual al input tipo date
document.getElementById('fecha').value = today;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mostrar Fecha Actual</title>
</head>
<body>

<label for="fecha">Selecciona una fecha:</label>
<input type="date" id="fecha">

</body>
</html>
```

en este caso con las dos linea de codigo nos encargamos del obtener la fecha y convertirlo al formato YYYY-MM-DD para el input date.

### Ahora hiremos por un poco de escalabilidad:

si esto pretendes usarlo en diferentes lugares lo ideal seria utilizar un wrap que se encargue de ejecutar toda la logica y eso lo logramos mediante un metodo/funcion:

```js
// Función para obtener y establecer la fecha actual en un input tipo date
function establecerFechaActualEnInput(inputId) {
    const input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    if (input) {
        input.value = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    } else {
        console.error(`No se encontró el elemento con el ID ${inputId}`);
    }
}

// Llamar a la función para establecer la fecha actual en el input con ID 'fecha'
establecerFechaActualEnInput('fecha');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mostrar Fecha Actual</title>
</head>
<body>

<label for="fecha">Selecciona una fecha:</label>
<input type="date" id="fecha">

</body>
</html>
```

como veras estoy implementando un ID para identificar en que lugar quiero ese valor.