# Asignar valor a un input tipo fecha

Tags: javascript

Tengo un input tipo fecha, y quiero asignarle un valor...

```
<input type="date"  id="fechaplazoC" name="fechaplazoC" align='left'  value="" style="text-align:left;">
```

Intento cambiar el valor:

```
 var f = new Date();
 f.setDate(f.getDate() + (d*num)); //Calculo la nueva Fecha.
 newfecha= f.getFullYear() + '-' +(f.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + f.getDate();//obtengo por ejemplo 2024-10-12

 document.getElementById("fechaplazoC").value=newfecha
```

No cambia el valor en el input...alguna idea ???

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mostrar fecha actual en input tipo date con JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167506/mostrar-fecha-actual-en-input-tipo-date-con-javascript)

Comment: Usa `document.getElementById("fechaplazoC").valueAsDate=f` sin usar un string. Por otro lado tu error está en que los números menores a 10 para los dias y meses requieren anteponer un cero (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08.09) -> `2024-03-11` es correcto, en cambio `2024-3-11` es incorrecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en que si el mes o el día son menores a 10 tiene que ir un 0 delante.

Aquí te dejo el código corregido:

```
var f = new Date();
f.setDate(f.getDate() + (d*num)); //Calculo la nueva Fecha.
var month = ('0' + (f.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // Asegura que el mes siempre tenga dos dígitos
var day = ('0' + f.getDate()).slice(-2); // Asegura que el día siempre tenga dos dígitos
var newfecha = f.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day; //obtengo por ejemplo 2024-10-12

document.getElementById("fechaplazoC").value = newfecha;
```